# Python. Разбить список на несколько переменных

Tags: python-3.x

Помогите решить задачку: есть переменная такого вида ard = [R:4531,G:2010,B:2129,C:8669,Lux:14.14].
Требуется получить 5 списков чисел для значений "R", "G", "B", "C", "Lux". По индексу не получается, так как значения могут прийти без буквенного обозначения, на них внимания тогда не обращаем. То есть нужен фильтр: если R - в список R значений и так далее.

Comment: `[R:4531,G:2010,B:2129,C:8669,Lux:14.14]` что это за тип вообще? Добавьте в вопрос, какой результат хотите получить

Comment: Это список данных, приходящих с арудино: характеристики цвета и освещенности. Требуется разбить их на списки по характеристикам(список R числовых значений, список Lux числовых значений)  для нахождения среднего значения для каждого в реальном времени.

Answer (score 2):

```
ard = ['R:4531','G:2010','B:2129','C:8669','Lux:14.14']
R = []
G = []
B = []
C = []
Lux = []
for a in ard:
  index = a.split(':')[0]
  value = a.split(':')[1]
  if index == 'R':
    R.append(value)
  elif index == 'G':
    G.append(value)
  elif index == 'B':
    B.append(value)
  elif index == 'C':
    C.append(value)
  elif index == 'Lux':
    Lux.append(value)

print('R: ', R)
print('G: ', G)
print('B: ', B)
print('C: ', C)
print('Lux: ', Lux)
```

Выход:

```
R:  ['4531']
G:  ['2010']
B:  ['2129']
C:  ['8689']
Lux:  ['14.14']
```

Но лучше через словарь делать )

```
thisdict = {
  "R": 4531,
  "G": 2010,
  "B": 2129,
  "C": 8669,
  "Lux": 14.14
}

print('R: ', thisdict['R'])
print('G: ', thisdict['G'])
print('B: ', thisdict['B'])
print('C: ', thisdict['C'])
print('Lux: ',  thisdict['Lux'])
```

Выход:

```
R:  4531
G:  2010
B:  2129
C:  8669
Lux:  14.14
```